# keypress event is not working in magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I'm having problems with keypress events.first i am enter the key then it's working but next time enter the key is not working.Please tell me what's going wrong with my code:

html code:

```
      <div class="findbysku">
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="q" id="finder" title="Model #" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = this.defaultValue;}" onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {this.value = '';}" value="Model #" on/> 
                <button class="button" title="Search" id="finder_find" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
```

javascript code:

```
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

     $.noConflict(); 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var options, a;
    jQuery(function(){
        options = { serviceUrl:'<?php echo $url; ?>finder/index/loadproductsbyquery', 
                    onSelect: function(value, data){ open_product(data);  },
                    maxHeight:400,
                    minChars:3,
                    width:300,
                    noCache: false
                  };
        a = jQuery('#finder').autocomplete(options);
    });          

    jQuery('#finder').keypress(function(event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

           if (a.data.length > 0 ) {

               open_product(a.data[0]);

           }
        }
    });

    jQuery('#finder_find').click(function() {  

           if (a.data.length > 0 ) {    

               open_product(a.data[0]);
           }        

    });

    jQuery('.list-categories select').change(function() {
        window.open(jQuery(this).val(),'_self');    
    }); 
});

jQuery("#sample-review-click").fancybox({
    padding : 0  
});

jQuery("#guidelines-click").fancybox({
    autoSize    : true,
    maxWidth    : 600,

}); 
function open_product(data) {

    jQuery('.product-container').css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
    jQuery.post('<?php echo $url; ?>finder/index/getproductinfo',{ id: data} , function(response) {
        var response_array=JSON.parse( response );                   
        var url=response_array.url+"#box-Reviews";
        window.location.href = url;
    });             
}   

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`keypress` event is working fine.Probably some other issue

```
  $.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#finder').on('keypress',function(event) {
        alert(event.keyCode)
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

           if (a.data.length > 0 ) {

               open_product(a.data[0]);

           }
        }
    });

})
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/9Lwvposz/1/)

NOTE: From [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keypress.asp) The order of events related to the keypress event:

```
    keydown - The key is on its way down
    keypress - The key is pressed down
    keyup - The key is released
```

However, the keypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC). Use the keydown() method to also check these keys.